# What type of bulb fits in this slot type?

Tags: light-fixture, light

We have this light fixture outside and the the bulb has always been missing.

It has two side slots and twists into place once fully inserted.

My Google searching and hardware store searches have come up empty.

What is this bulb and how can I replace it?[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's called a [Bayonet Mount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayonet_mount) (in your case, single contact, as there's a double contact as well)

> A bayonet mount (mainly as a method of mechanical attachment, as for fitting a lens to a camera) or bayonet connector (for electrical use) is a fastening mechanism consisting of a cylindrical male side with one or more radial pins, and a female receptor with matching L-shaped slot(s) and with spring(s) to keep the two parts locked together. The slots are shaped like a capital letter L with serif (a short upward segment at the end of the horizontal arm); the pin slides into the vertical arm of the L, rotates across the horizontal arm, then is pushed slightly upwards into the short vertical "serif" by the spring; the connector is no longer free to rotate unless pushed down against the spring until the pin is out of the "serif".
>
> The bayonet mount is the standard light bulb fitting in the United Kingdom and in many countries that were members of the British Empire including Pakistan, Australia, India, Sri Lanka, Ireland, and New Zealand, parts of the Middle East and Africa and, historically, France and Greece.

You can see the knobs on the bulb base in [this product page](http://www.bulbs.com/product/1141?RefId=25)

[image]

Comment: I have a fixture like that on an outside mast. I use 12 V  12 W "automotive" bulbs in it. Mine has two of the sockets in series and the pair are powered by a 24 V ac transformer plugged into a receptacle inside which is controlled by a single pole wall switch. I formerly used 12 V 24 W bulbs in this socket, but these produced so much heat that it destroyed the socket so I downsized to 12 W and the sockets have lasted far longer than before.

Comment: In the U.S., most lights on automobiles except for the headlamps used to use this.